# How to count input that have value?

Tags: php, forms, input, count, submit

in my code,  when we click ok button . It's will echo 3

I want to apply to count only input that have value only

How to do ?

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
     echo count($_POST["to_more"]);
    }
?>
<form name="f1" method="post">
<input type="text" name="to_more[]">
<input type="text" name="to_more[]">
<input type="text" name="to_more[]">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

Comment: loop it than only you will get the count.

Comment: loop $_POST['to_more'] and if it contains value then count them

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
     echo count(array_filter($_POST["to_more"]));
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
     $count = 0 ;
     foreach($_POST["to_more"] as $data){
                if($data != '') $count++;

     }
         if($count > 0)
                echo $count;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_filter` should help

```
<?php
    $ar = isset($_POST["to_more"]) ? $_POST["to_more"] : array();
    $ar = array_filter($ar, function($el){ return !empty($el);});
    echo count($ar);
?>
```

Should be quicker than foreach, btw.

UPD: Oh, seems, NLSaini posted the precise solution, check it.